React Native app with version <=0.65 for android is crashing in real device when targetSdkVersion is bumped from 33 to 34
I am using RN version 0.64.0. When I changed targetSdkVersion from 33 to 34, my react native android is crashing.
ENV:
RN: 0.64.0
Node: 16.16.0
Gradle version (updated): 7.4.2
Gradle plugin version (updated): 7.3.0
I've updated the following packages versions in package.json to the ones that I felt its compatible to 0.64.0.
  
"@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "6.0.0",
"react-native-screens": "2.17.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "2.2.0",

//android/build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext {
        androidSvgVersion = '1.2.1'
        appAuthVersion = '0.7.1'
        bitmovinCollectorVersion = '2.6.1'
        bitmovinPlayerVersion = '3.24.2'
        buildToolsVersion = '31.0.0'
        excludeAppGlideModule = true
        glideVersion = '4.11.0'
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        timberVersion = '4.5.1'
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.21'
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${project.ext.kotlinVersion}"
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        /*  android build throws minSdk not compatible for androidx.appcompat and it looks like the dependency versions are read from maven and not node_modules.
            Hence exclusiveContent block is required to ensure that dependency versions are read from node_modules and not from maven.
            It may not be required when react native version is upgraded to 0.71.0.
        */
        exclusiveContent{
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }

            }
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://bitmovin.jfrog.io/artifactory/public-releases' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}

// TODO: React Native libraries (linked as project modules) with native code need to have a unified `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`.
// 3rd party dependencies usually have differing versions used and are not always using the latest ones (a *known* issue in the RN ecosystem). We work around this by using Gradle's `subproject` API (refer to the top-level/root `build.gradle` file).
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if (subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library')) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried as suggested by the communities. I did the following change, the app is working in debug mode, but crashed in the release mode when I installed in the real device.
MainApplication.java file

import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Build;
    import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
    @Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
            return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
        } else {
            return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
    }
 
// android/app/build.gradle
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'

Then while finding answers someone has pointed me to https://medium.com/@zahitesh/android-14-sdk-34-support-for-react-native-ver-0-69-x-2554f4dc937d. i tried doing that but i got the following error
cd android && ./gradlew ReactAndroid:installArchives
It gives below error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Project 'ReactAndroid' not found in root project 'MyProjectName''.

Also from this post SDK update 33 to 34 I understand that the PlayCore library has been updated to Android 14 and recommends to update the PlayCore Maven dependency in the project. But i thought the fix above takes takes care of it. Also since it's run time, its hard to say. I'm not sure what Maven dependency to update it.
My question here is I'm sure there might be some apps running versions with RN <= 0.65.0. Can anyone tell me what's the problem in the run time. Is it the problem of the patch mentioned above can't be applied to the version < 0.73.0. If there is any help, I would highly appreciate as i've tried all ways on my end to fix this. And i'm in a dire need to roll out soon as my time is ticking for the other project.

Why aren't you upgrading your RN version? A version <= 0.65 is considered old.

@tomerpacific
There are dependencies and libraries that'll break. We're currently revamping the app with new RN version 0.73.4. Its half way through, but until such time, we need to maintain the existing ones. And this one came in between with a deadline. And we can't afford to spending more time to refactor the existing ones. Hope I'm clear. But if there is any solution that you're aware, Please let me know.

I finally figured out the answer for this.
The problem was the Gradle version and Gradle plugin version weren't compatible that was breaking the release build. However, when I set both the Gradle version 7.0.2 and the Gradle plugin version to 7.0, it worked like a charm. To anyone out there for the RN <= 0.65.0 this should positively work.
Good luck!!!
